# How would this machine code look like in C?

Tags: c, assembly

I have this machine code that I have been struggling with for the past 4 days, but I can't seem to get the hold of it.

```
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    jmp .L3
L4:
    addl $3,8(%ebp)

L3:
    movl 8(%ebp),%eax // having issues here
    movzbl (%eax),%eax//here
    cmpb $1,%al// and here
    je .L5
    cmpl 12(%ebp),%eax
    jne .L4
    movl $8,%eax
.L5: leave
     ret
```

Here's my attempt at the solution:

```
int main(int s, char *t){
    while (s != 1) {
        if (s == *t){
            s = 8;
        }
        else{s+=3;}
    }
    return;
}
```

Can someone tell me if I'm approaching this correctly? and if not help me point to the right direction?

Comment: That's not a valid `main` signature. `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is the usual form.

Comment: ah sorry about that, I was not sure if that would affect the machine code or not.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: why do you think this is `main` and not some other function?

Comment: @DCoder I was commenting on OP's `main` method; presumably, OP intends this equivalent C program to run.

Comment: it doesn't necessarily have to run, but I'm trying to learn harder machine code. The problem is I found this on a website but could not find an answer to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function looks to be __cdecl because it refers to `8(%ebp)` and `12(%ebp)` without initializing either, which indicates that they are arguments. Call them `arg1` and `arg2` respectively.

We can annotate the assembly:

```
    /* Function prologue */
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    jmp .L3
L4:
    /* Move to next loop iteration */
    addl $3, arg1

L3:
    /* Copy value of arg1 to %eax */
    movl arg1, %eax
    /* (%eax) means to dereference %eax (as a memory address).
       movzbl means to load a single byte and zero-extend to the rest of the register.
       Therefore, the byte at address %eax is put into %eax. */
    movzbl (%eax), %eax
    /* Compare the low byte of %eax against 1 */
    cmpb $1, %al
    /* If equal, exit (%eax = 1) */
    je .L5
    /* Compare %eax against arg2 */
    cmpl arg2, %eax
    /* If not equal, keep looping */
    jne .L4

    /* Otherwise, if it was equal, we quit and return %eax = 8 */
    movl $8,%eax
.L5: leave
     ret
```

In C code, this becomes

```
int fn(unsigned char *ptr, int sentinel) {
    while(1) {
        unsigned char c = *ptr;
        if(c == 1) return c;
        if(c == sentinel) return 8;
        ptr += 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough explanation, I was pulling hairs when I couldn't see movzbl and cmpb when I was disassembling it!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an annotated version of the disassembly:

```
    pushl %ebp        // save frame pointer
    movl %esp, %ebp   // setup new stack frame

    // The stack frame looks like this:
    // 0(%ebp) : previous frame pointer
    // 4(%ebp) : return address
    // 8(%ebp) : unsigned char *arg1
    // 12(%ebp) : int arg2

    jmp .L3                // jump to loop body
L4:
    addl $3,8(%ebp)        // arg1 += 3

L3:
    movl 8(%ebp),%eax      // %eax = arg1
    movzbl (%eax),%eax     // %eax = *arg1 (zero-extend from byte to dword)
    cmpb $1,%al            // *arg1 == 1?

    je .L5

    // *arg1 != 1
    cmpl 12(%ebp),%eax     // arg2 == *arg1?

    jne .L4

    // *arg1 == arg2
    movl $8,%eax           // result = 8

.L5: leave
     ret
```

From this, we can attempt to write the equivalent C code:

```
int f(unsigned char *p, int v)
{
    unsigned char b;

    for(; (b = *p) != 1; p += 3) {
        if(b == v)
            return 8;
    }

    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More like this, assuming CDECL calling standard.

```
int fn(int s, int t){
    for(;*(char*)s != 1 && s != t;s += 3);
    if(s == t)
        return 8;
    else
        return s;
}
```

Here's an explaination of the ones you said you didn't get.

```
movl 8(%ebp),%eax // Load s from stack into register eax.
movzbl (%eax),%eax // Load a byte from the address in eax (s) and set the higher 3 bytes of eax to 0.
cmpb $1,%al // Compare that byte loaded to 1.
```

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain the `*(char*)s` portion to me, I'm still kind of new at this

Comment: It casts s to a char* (the address of a char/byte), the * says to retrieve the byte at the address in s. To cast is to signify to the compiler that a variable of one type should be treated like a variable of another type in that expression. So `(char*)0` would mean that the compiler should take 0, an int, and treat it as if it is the address of an char. You may have seen `NULL` before; it is simply a constant for `(void*)0`.